# Windows Subsystem for Linux swap space too large, Windows 10

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, swap, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I noticed my disk space has shrunk considerably. So I checked my bash on windows, running free -h command:

```
  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.9G        4.3G        3.4G         17M        230M        3.5G
Swap:           24G         12M         23G
```

The swap space is huge and obviously unnecessarily huge.

I've tried ways, including swapon/off, but none of them work. In fact swapon/off does not seem to be supported here.

Could anyone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Your main problems seems to a lack of available system memory.  It appears you only have 12 MB free on your swap, so you actually need that much space, appears you need more

Comment: Your title is confusing the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) which your asking about has little to do with Bash on Ubuntu.  This is a WSL issue not a Bash on Ubuntu problem

Comment: thanks, updated. what does the shared swap space here mean?

Comment: I would assume it's the shared space between WSL and Windows.  24GB page file isn't that large, it also, is the expected size based on your described system